# Responsive web design with inline css

Tags: html, css

I am actually creating an email signature with actual coding (For Gmail) and it looked just fine on the computer web. Unfortunately, the mobile version of the signature didn't turn out well and i wanted to try solutions like media queries, etc.. but Gmail only inputs **INLINE CSS** and unable to validate **Outline CSS** .

I tried using table, tr , td to think that the table would help to adjust automatically in the mobile but to no avail.  Will anyone be able to recommend me any solution for this?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        $container1   
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0;    padding:0;border:0">
            <tr>
                <td width="450">  
                    <div id="minicontainer1" style="padding: 5px 0 0 20px; height:80px;line-height:50%;box-sizing:border-box;"> 
                        <p class="font1" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold; color:black;"> $name </p> 
                        <p class="font2" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:9.5pt; color:black;"> $position </p>         
                        <p class="font2" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:9.5pt; color:black;"> $cell </p> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="minicontainer2" style="  padding:0 0 0 20px; margin-top:-10px; line-height:50%;box-sizing:border-box;">
                        <p class="font1 diffsize" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; color:black;"> $company  </p>
                        <div class="font2 diffsize" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:8pt; color:black; line-height: 12px;"> 
                            <p> $address. </p> 
                            <p> Phone : <span id="special" style="color: #0000EE !important; text-decoration: underline;"> $telno </span> | Fax :<span id="special" style="color: #0000EE !important; text-decoration: underline;"> $faxno </span> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </td>
```

This is just a small example for it and to show u how i have to use Inline CSS for everything. The file has php, html and css. Bootstrap is most likely unavailable too.

Just for visualization:

[web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhiR9.png)

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekhme.png)

Comment: Come up with a fiddle so that it will be much more easier to provide solution. How ever your HTML markup is incomplete

Comment: just a sample. I am obligated to display the whole code

Comment: What is the expected outcome? you want the `minicontainers` to stack on small screens?

Comment: If you are okay with alternative solution, follow below steps:
1. Use [mail-chimp](http://mailchimp.com/) to create a layout
2. Edit the code in middle as you required
3. Send a test mail to your gmail id
4. Get the code using inspect elements

Comment: the problem is this. Since the code that you have exposed does not give sufficient clarity. may be you can remove the content and mock a sample to get your work done. after that you can integrate it to your real application.

Comment: @Aaron I added visualization if it helps. One is for web and another one is for mobile. The outcome i would like is to have the mobile to be exactly like the web

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I am not sure if you can override using this technique

You can put this in internal css or external css.

```
<style>
    table {
        margin: 20px !important; // for example only
    }
</style>
```

Put !important to every value. This works well for me. If it helped you. Notify me. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry.. I dont understand. I have to set !important for every inline css?

Comment: You should try to avoid using !important as much as possible, it makes CSS really complicated and difficult to manage especially when media queries are involved

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja On his project. You can't override inline css without using !important or javascript. That's the easiest solution he can have. Or else he should recreate his web project. Using external is much better. And this is commonly used in overriding bootstrap value.

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja Not only that but if you're using style tags for an email it's recommened that you use the `!important` with each style.